# Cant get the text value from input text

Tags: javascript

when i try to get the text value from the input text, the value returned is "undefined". This function return:  "username: undefined" and my input text have a value.

```
this.loadForm = function() {

        $("#response-container").load("formLogin.php", function() {

            $("#formLogin").submit(function(event) {

               var user = $("#username").val();

                alert("username: "+user);

                event.preventDefault();    

            });

        });

    }; //END loadForm FUNCTION
```

formLogin.php

```
<form id="formLogin" method="get" action="20.html">
    USERNAME:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <br> PASSWORD:
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <br>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" name="login" id="btnInputLogin" onsubmit="return false" />
</form>
```

Comment: You don't have element with id `username`

Comment: @u_mulder Oh what a noob i am, i was thinking the name was the id, sorry and thank u, glad your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check Your Selector**

You need to use an `id` attribute if you are using the `$('#id')` syntax in jQuery as the `#` indicates that you are explicitly targeting an element with the `id` attribute that follows the `#` character:

```
<input type="text" id='username' name="username" />
```

If you want to reference something by a name, you would need to use [an attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to explicitly target the name attribute :

```
var user = $('[name="username"]').val();
```

Comment: Nice catch, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no input with `#username`. Either add that `id` attribute or use

```
$('input[name="username"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

To

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, noob mistake!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your jquery here: `$("#username").val();` is trying to get an id that doesn't exist.

You could add an id to the password input `<input id="password">` which should work.

Or you can get it with the current name `$('[name="password"]').val()`